# How does bombarding a molecule with electrons cause ionization?

Tags: electrons, mass-spectrometry

I am a chemistry student, and my current are of study is mass spectrometry.

In the ionization process, atoms are bombarded with electrons, but how does this work? I assume the flow of electrons attract the electrons of the atom, thereby removing them, but where do the atom's electrons go?

Comment: Electrons do not attract electrons, they would repel each other as they have like charge.

Comment: Imagine the analogy of you holding on to an object (let's say your groceries) then someone chucks stuff at you. You might accidentally drop the groceries. While this is obviously not an accurate analogy on an atomic level, it might help to visualise what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of ionization is known as electron ionization (there are many types of ionization methods used for MS). One possible reaction for EI is:
$$\ce{M +e- ->M^{•+} +2e-}$$ [source](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E01999.html)

If the incoming electron has the correct energy to interact and passes close enough to the molecule, it's electric field can impart enough energy to one of the molecule's electrons for it to be ejected. What happens to the electrons after that isn't particularly important as far as ionization is concerned, but in most EI sources, electrons are emitted perpendicular to the axis of the sample source and are collected on the other side by an electrode, preventing charging of the source chamber and focusing the emitted electrons into a beam.

Comment: A lot of people call it "electron impact ionization" or "EI" instead of just "electron ionization".

Comment: Yes, that's the older term for it. IUPAC [discourages](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E01999.html) its use now.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't understand the reason for half the stuff IUPAC does.  Why would they do that?

Comment: "Note: Electrons and photons do not "impact" molecules or atoms. They interact with them in ways that result in various electronic excitations including ionization. For this reason it is recommended that the terms 'electron impact' and 'photon impact' not be used."—from [Recommendations for nomenclature and symbolism for mass spectroscopy](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.1991.63.issue-10/pac199163101541/pac199163101541.xml)

Comment: I see that IUPAC recommendation was from 1991.  I learned everything I know about mass spectrometry well after that, and can report that "electron impact" is still widely used.  I can kind of see the point of the change, but on the other hand, the same exact argument could be used to say that "The bat does not 'impact' the ball; it interacts with it in ways that result in various trajectories for the ball including home runs."

Comment: It's my experience that chemists ignore or simply aren't aware of a lot of IUPAC recommendations and I don't think it's a big deal in this case. But the difference, of course, in the two examples is that a classical collision model is a very good explanation for a macroscopic baseball but fails to correctly describe much of the behaviour of a photon or electron interacting with an atom.